# Reading a comma-seperated list of numbers fails C

Tags: c, fopen

I have a file containing a list of numbers separated by commas. I tried different methods of reading data, and this piece of code has worked without issues on different datasets.

Input for example (600 values): https://pastebin.com/AHJ5UpEu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <mem.h>

#define READ "r"
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 4096
#define DATA_DELIMITER ","


unsigned char *readInput(const char *filename, size_t inputs) {
    unsigned char *input = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * inputs);
    unsigned char nbr;
    const char *token;
    int i;

    FILE *inputPtr = fopen(filename, READ);
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, inputPtr)) {
        nbr = 0;
        for (token = strtok(line, DATA_DELIMITER); token && *token; token = strtok(NULL, ",\n")) {
            input[nbr] = (unsigned char) atoi(token);
            nbr++;
        }
        break;
    }

    fclose(inputPtr);

    if(nbr != inputs){
        printf("Error, did not read all files. Only read %d\n",nbr);
        exit(-1);
    }
    exit(0);
}

int main() {


    unsigned char *d = readInput("../traces/inputs.dat", 600);
    free(d);
    exit(0);
}
```

Though it only reads the first 88 values. If I change the max-line-size to for example 512, this number is 145.
Though the value should - if I understand this correct - be equal to the length of the line, in my case ~2100 characters. So using 4098 shouldn't be an issue.

Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

How come I'm not reading all 600 values, but only parts of the data?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: When you read a partial line you reset `nbr`. Move `nbr = 0;` outside the loop.

Comment: Q: are you SURE there is no line break or #0 in your file ? what happens if you remove the break ? Your code can read more than a single line when nbr=0 is placed above the loop..

Comment: Not really sure why `nbr` is an unsigned **char**. You realize that thing will only have 256 entries before it overflows back to zero, so your 600 entries is wishful thinking. And even after fixing that, and fixing the 0-assignment to outside the loop, this is still asking for problems, including landing on a partial entry read (the end of the fgets read landing in the *middle* of an element, reading the rest on the next iteration). And if course, `nbr < inputs` should be one of the conditions in your while loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just dropped my whiskey! Hahaha, you are right! Good catch mate!

Comment: I can tell you from experience. coding while on whiskey is ultimately not very constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**nbr** is being used like an integer counter but is defined as an unsigned char. A char is one byte, and an unsigned byte has a range of 0 to 255. Incrementing beyond 255 will cause the byte to overflow and return to a value of 0. So, currently, nbr is actually the total number of entries processed mod 256.

Comment: @WhozCraig beat me to it in the comments on the OP :P

Comment: Yes, as @WhozCraig said, you are right. A glass of whisky made me overlook that. This is what I love about C - you have complete control, also to f**k up.